# mod_python returns a blank screen

Tags: python, apache2, mod-python

I'm trying to run mod_python.publisher in apache2. All I want to do is simply print "Hello World"

When I run my program, I get a blank screen.
My .py program looks like this:

```
def index():
    print ("Hello World")
index()
```

However when I run the program:

```
def index(req):
    print ("Hello World")
index()
```

I get this error message that says index() requires and argument and 0 is given:

```
MOD_PYTHON ERROR

ProcessId:      23348
Interpreter:    'test.com'

ServerName:     'test.com'
DocumentRoot:   '/var/www'

URI:            '/modPythonTest.py'
Location:       None
Directory:      '/var/www/'
Filename:       '/var/www/modPythonTest.py'
PathInfo:       ''

Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'mod_python.publisher'

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537,                    in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1229,     in _process_target
    result = _execute_target(config, req, object, arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1128,     in _execute_target
    result = object(arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 204,     in handler
    module = page_cache[req]

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1059,     in __getitem__
    return import_module(req.filename)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 296,     in import_module
    log, import_path)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 680,     in import_module
    execfile(file, module.__dict__)

  File "/var/www/modPythonTest.py", line 5, in <module>
    index()

    TypeError: index() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

So based on that, I looks like my code is being compiled. I get an error from bad code, but no output on good code. Any ideas?

Comment: You added the parameter `req` to  the index function, but your call to `index()` does not provide one, e.g. `index(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from mod_python import apache

def index(req):
    out = "<html><head>"
    out = out+"<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html'></head>"
    out = out+"<body>Hello World</body></html>"
```